# Angular: Is there a way to consume observable directly in a template?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Is there a way I can directly consume value emitted by the observable in a template.

What I want to do is consume observable value and construct a string out of it.

For example
`[style]="width: {progress$ | async}%"`

I tried doing this

```
<div class="progress">
  <div
    class="progress-bar"
    role="progressbar"
    [style]="width: {{progress | async}}%;"
    aria-valuenow="25"
    aria-valuemin="0"
    aria-valuemax="100"
  ></div>
</div>
```

But I keep getting the error

```
Failed to compile.

Error: Quotes are not supported for evaluation!
        Statement:  {{progress$ | async}}%; located at C:/Aditya/playground/practice/Angular/progress-bar/src/app/progress-bar/progress-bar.component.html@4:13
```

Comment: Remove the brackets around `[style]=` → `style=`

Comment: Try this way **style='width:  {{progress | async}}'**.

Comment: You shouldn't template bind in your attributes, you should use property binding.

Answer (score 1):

This will work

`[style.width.%]="progress | async"`

Here is a StackBlitz demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9uueyg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html